# Correct Syntax; No Result

Tags: c#

I have a strange problem. I am trying to write a function that looks at a TextBox that, if it is equal to a certain value, changes the value of a string to something else.
Here is my code:

I define the string in Main:

```
string strDoorsOption1 = "test";
```

The Method is defined as:

```
public void optionCheck(TextBox txt, string str)
{
    if (txt.Text == "0")
    {
        str = "+++";
    }
    else
    {
        str = "---";
    }
}
```

I call the Method like this:

```
private void chkDoorsSafetyLaminated_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBoxClick3(chkDoorsSafetyLaminated, txtDoorsSafety1);
    optionCheck(txtDoorsSafety1, strDoorsOption1);
}
```

**checkBoxClick3** is another Method that works as intended to change the value of a TextBox.
For reference, it is defined as follows:

```
public void checkBoxClick3(CheckBox check, TextBox txt)
{
    /* Determine the CheckState of the Checkbox */
    if (check.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        /* If the CheckState is Checked, then set the value to 1 */
        txt.Text = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        /* If the CheckState is Unchecked, then set the value to 0 */
        txt.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

This works...:

```
if (txtDoorsSafety1.Text == "0")
{
    strDoorsOption1 = "+++";
}
else
{
    strDoorsOption1 = "---";
}
```

But when I call `optionCheck(txtDoorsSafety1, strDoorsOption1);` it acts as if the method is empty. It completely compiles with no errors or warnings, it simply does nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read some docs about `ref`, `out` keywords.

Comment: what do you mean by does nothing? actually that method is doing nothin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void optionCheck(TextBox txt, string str)
```

Passes the string by value (just like all references), which means the later assignment **does not affect the class level variable**. You changed the local copy, but nothing uses it.

Instead, pass by ref:

```
public void optionCheck(TextBox txt, ref string str)
```

Called as:

```
optionCheck(txtDoorsSafety1, ref strDoorsOption1);
```

Comment: That makes sense, I was aware that `ref` existed, but I couldn't figure out exactly how to use it. It seems strange to me that I have to use it both when defining the method and when calling it, and that is why it messed me up. Thank you.

Comment: @ZLHysong I don't know for sure, but I would imagine its required in both places so you *know* that its going to be (potentially) modified. That way you don't go "Why did my variable change after calling this function???"

Comment: it is required twice, but it just seems counterintuitive to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void optionCheck(TextBox txt, string str)
```

The string `str` is passed by value, not by its reference. This means in this case, that if you change it, it will not change the string, but create a new reference. This reference is only availble inside this method.

The `public void checkBoxClick3(CheckBox check, TextBox txt)` works, because `txt.Text` is a property inside the `TextBox` object, this its reference is always kept even outside the method.

You can fix the first method by using the `ref` keyword to make it act like you want (i.e. actually pass by reference)

```
public void optionCheck(TextBox txt, ref string str)
```

which you also need to use the keyword when calling:

```
optionCheck(txtDoorsSafety1, ref strDoorsOption1);
```

Although, a more conventional approach would be to simply let the `optionCheck` method actually return a string instead of modifying its input:

```
public string optionCheck(TextBox txt, string str)
```

Then call like

```
strDoorsOption1 = optionCheck(txtDoorsSafety1, strDoorsOption1);
```

Comment: I have already selected an accepted answer, but you are correct as well, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It does nothing. True.
You are making str reference a new object. To make it work, you need to use pass-by-reference.

```
public void optionCheck(TextBox txt, ref string str)
{
    if (txt.Text == "0")
    {
        str = "+++";
    }
    else
    {
        str = "---";
   }
   //or:
   str = txt.Text == "0" ? "+++" : "---";
}
```

Then, you call it with: `optionCheck(txtDoorsSafety1, ref strDoorsOption1);`

Alternatively, you can let the method return a value:

```
public string optionCheck(TextBox txt, string str)
{
    return txt.Text == "0" ? "+++" : "---";
}
```

Then call it with: `strDoorsOption1 = optionCheck(txtDoorsSafety1, strDoorsOption1);`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you, unfortunately, someone else got the accepted answer for the same thing already.

Comment: @ZLHysong That is not uncommon on stackoverflow :) Before you finish typing, a couple of answers appear.

Answer (score 1):

if you need return a parameter value, you need use a references parameter try this code:

```
public void optionCheck(TextBox txt, ref string str)
{
    if (txt.Text == "0")
    {
        str = "+++";
    }
    else
    {
        str = "---";
    }
}

public void checkBoxClick3(CheckBox check, ref string txt)
{
    /* Determine the CheckState of the Checkbox */
    if (check.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        /* If the CheckState is Checked, then set the value to 1 */
        txt = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        /* If the CheckState is Unchecked, then set the value to 0 */
        txt = "0";
    }
}
```

you can use ref or out, if you use ref is necessary declare the parameter before of the use

Comment: checkBoxClick3 Works as it is, but the `ref` is what I was missing, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Step through the code in a debugger and examine the runtime values.  When the method sets a value on `str`, does `strDoorsOption1` also get updated?  My guess is that it does not, and that the `string` is being passed by value (whereas things like `CheckBox` are passed by reference).

Instead of trying to modify the parameters being passed to the method, have the method simply return a value.  Then the consuming code can set that value where it needs to be.  Something like this:

```
public string optionCheck(TextBox txt)
{
    if (txt.Text == "0")
    {
        return "+++";
    }
    else
    {
        return "---";
    }
}
```

Then in consuming code:

```
strDoorsOption1  = optionCheck(txtDoorsSafety1);
```

Returning the results of a calculation tends to be a lot more intuitive than modifying the parameters of a method, which can often be viewed as an unintuitive or unadvertised side-effect of calling the method.

Comment: This is not what I want to do, though I can see the pattern here. This method will be called over 20 different times, and the other methods (using `ref`) are what I was looking for.